# I'm getting into sit and go tournament finals so much, but how can I come first more?

Tags: poker-strategy

I keep on coming second likely because of bad decision making (just started out), but I've found that when it's down to two people blinds are so high and everyone gets so restless and just starts all inning which puts things down to luck more than skill.

Comment: How many tournaments are you talking about? Without a sizeable sample of at least a hundred, if not more, tournaments, it's really hard to say. And often when you get down to stacks of < 10 BB, it is just a matter of luck.

Comment: Yes binds are big and you have to take your chances.  You need to be willing to gamble.   Q8 is a good hand heads up and it will get beat.

Comment: @HerbWolfe I'm more asking for advice on macro strategy for when it's just you and another person.

Comment: @Paparazzi what did you mean by the last sentence?

Comment: I don't know how else to say it.   SE is not a discussion forum. There are whole books on head up play.

Answer (score 0):

Your macro strategy should depend very heavily on the number of BBs you and the other guy have.   As Herb said with less than 10BB it's all about all ins pre flop pretty much.  There's no way around that.  When both of you have over 20 bbs if the opponent keeps shoving then you can afford to be a little patient and will catch him out more often than not.  Even so, you'll likely only get your money in as a 60/40 favorite.